# Group By day for custom time interval

Tags: cratedb

I'm very new to SQL and time series database. I'm using crate database. I want to aggregate the data by day. **But the I want to start each day start time is 9 AM not 12AM.**.

Time interval  is  9 AM to 11.59 PM.

Unix time stamp is used to store the data. following is my sample database.

```
|sensorid | reading    | timestamp|
====================================
|1        | 1616457600 | 10       |
|1        | 1616461200 | 100      | 
|2        | 1616493600 | 1        |
|2        | 1616493601 | 10        |
```

Currently i grouped using following command. But it gives the start time as 12 AM.

```
select date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) as day,sum(reading)
from sensor1  v(timestamp)
group by  (DAY)
```

From the above table. i want sum of  1616493600 and 1616493601 data  (11 is result). because  1616457600 and 1616461200 are less than 9 am data.

Comment: I understand this as: the result is correct, but you want to show 9:00 instead of 0:00. Is this correct? Or do you want to exclude earlier times, such as 8:10 from the calculation?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner  .i want to group the data from 9 am .No need to sum 12-9 am data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add nine hours to midnight:

```
date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) + interval '9' hour
```

**Edit:** If you want to exclude hours before 9:00 from the data you add up, you must add a `WHERE` clause:

```
where extract(hour from v.timestamp) >= 9
```

Here is a complete query with all relevant data:

```
select
  date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) as day,
  date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) + interval '9' hour as day_start,
  min(v.timestamp) as first_data,
  max(v.timestamp) as last_data,
  sum(reading) as total_reading
from sensor1  v(timestamp)
where extract(hour from v.timestamp) >= 9
group by day
order by day;
```

Comment: inserted values  at 1616457600 (12am) , 1616461200 (1am) and 1616493600(am).
Then query issued with the +interval '9' hour , But sum of the all value is grouped

Comment: select date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) + interval '9' hour as day,sum(reading)from sensor1  v(timestamp) group by  (DAY) limit 100;

Comment: If you want to exclude data from what you select, then use a `WHERE` clause. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: it is possible to set end time ?  (shift time 9am to 10pm)

Comment: `and extract(hour from v.timestamp) < 10`. This was not difficult, was it?